# Gerund or infinitive? Can you figure out a particular example for me?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I'm puzzled, really.

In the following example, how come the word ending in the -ing form is a verb.

-- I don't like dancing.

I know that 'like' here is a linking verb and can't be let alone without the thing being not liked. But, I can still say sth like, 'I don't like you...cheese...computers.' And clearly, the objects are rather nouny more than verb-like, right?

I can understand the sentence when having been reformulated as 'I don't like to dance'. Here it is crystal clear that to dance is an infinitive form of a verb, and as such being a verb.

Anyone?

Comment: Dancing" is strictly speaking ambiguous, but verb preferred (cf. "I don't like to dance"). Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "occasional dancing", in which case "occasional dancing" is object of "like". "Like" is not a linking verb; here it's a catenative verb with the non-finite clause "dancing" as catenative complement.

Answer (score 1):

*Dancing* in your example may be interpreted as either a participle or a gerund (or *nouny*, which I find very pleasing!), but it is most likely to be seen as a verb form because *to like* here is a *[catenative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb):* it is followed directly by another verb.

As BillJ says, if *dancing* were premodified (as in *occasional dancing*), that would force *dancing* to be seen as a noun form; but without that, *dancing* by itself, because it directly follows *like*, is seen as a clause that serves as the complement to *like.*

While *to like* can take either the infinitive or the gerund-participle, some other common catenative verbs can take only the marked infinitive, such as:

- hope
- appear
- seem
- come
- get
- fail

Others can take only the *-ing* form:

- go on
- keep
- keep on

In this instance, the writer may have chosen the *gerund-participle* "dancing" in preference to the infinitive "to dance" because there is a slight difference in meaning between the two statements:

> I don't like dancing.

This could mean that the speaker dislikes all dancing. Ballet, the waltz, popping and locking, you name it: he doesn't like it.

> I don't like to dance.

This means only that the speaker himself dislikes partaking in the activity.

Comment: +1, but I don't really like the first part. It should only be regarded as a gerund (or gerund-participle) since it realizes the object function.

Comment: @user178049 My explanation may need some work, then: a catenative verb _"prefers"_ a "verby" complement. "Dancing" isn't an _object_ here, it's a non-finite, one-word clause that serves as the complement to "like". (The term _"gerund-participle"_ is what modern grammars use when referring to the ~ing form of a verb.)

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised by the fact that a catenative complement is not regarded as an object here since it clearly answers the question 'What I don't like'.

Comment: @user178049 _Linking_ verbs take subject complements, but catenative verbs are followed directly by another verb.

Answer (score -1):

A gerund is used when the verb is treated like a noun:

> His ***running*** was the fastest I've seen.
>
> I'm not a fan of her ***cooking***.

Present progressive tense is used when the action (as a *verb*) is being done continuously:

> I am currently ***running***.
>
> He doesn't like to be bothered when he's ***cooking***.

Sometimes, (and English is notorious for this), the gerund/progressive form is used in many instances where the infinitive for of the verb would be more appropriate, so

> I don't like dancing.

Should be:

> I don't like **to dance**.

Both ways are natural-sounding ways to express this, so don't worry too much.

Comment: Actually, _"I don't like dancing"_ may mean that the speaker doesn't like even to watch _others_ dancing. _"I don't like to dance"_ means that the speaker prefers not to dance, but expresses nothing about dancing by others. There is sometimes a vast difference in meaning between usage of the infinitive and of the gerund-participle.